# Why is my slider tooltip not displaying text at start?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three sliders:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="time" >
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Days: <b>1</b> <input id="days" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="31" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,31]"/> <b>31</b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Months: <b>January</b> <input id="months" type="text" data-provide="slider" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="11" data-slider-tooltip="show" data-slider-value="[0,12]" /> <b>December</b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Years: <b>0</b> <input id="years" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="2017" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,2017]"/> <b>Today</b>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I use the following `js` (**note** it does many things but we're only looking for the the tooltip issue of `days` and `years`).

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
$("#days, #years").slider({
  tooltip: 'always',
}); 
$("#days").slider({
  formatter: function(value) {
    return 'Days: ' + value;
  }
});
$("#years").slider({
  formatter: function(value) {
    return 'Years: ' + value;
  }
});
$("#months").slider({
  tooltip: 'always',
  value: [0, 12],
  tooltip: 'always',
  formatter: function(value) {
     return months[value[0]] + " : " + months[value[1]];
  },
});
$("input").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    getData();
});
getData = function() {
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        data.push({
            day: $('#days').slider().val().split(',')[i], 
            month: months[$('#months').slider().val().split(',')[i]-1],
            year: $('#years').slider().val().split(',')[i], 
        }) ;
    }  
    console.log(data);
}
```

Before the range numbers of the sliders days and years, it should display (example) `Days: 22:16` and `Years 1200:1985` but the labels `Days` and `Years` appears only after we start interacting with the sliders but not at the very start when we load it

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/1335/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after checking the [unminified](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.1/bootstrap-slider.js) source code of the slider it looks like there needs to be an additional "refresh" call because formatter is not being called at the initialization phase. Just call `relayout` like this:

```
$("#days").slider({
  formatter: function(value) {
    return 'Days: ' + (value instanceof Array ? value.join(':'): value);
  }
}).slider('relayout');

$("#years").slider({
  formatter: function(value) {
    return 'Years: ' + (value instanceof Array ? value.join(':'): value);
  }
}).slider('relayout');
```

updated https://jsfiddle.net/pz3ce0o6/1340/

Comment: @rob.m Glad to help. Thank you.

Comment: mm check your fiddle, now the numbers are separated with a comma tho, while they should be `1733:1910`

Comment: @rob.m I see. Let me check.

Comment: @rob.m I updated the fiddle. The `value` is an array hence it needs to manually formatted using `join`.

Comment: @rob.m Hung is also right though about the double initialization.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151185/discussion-between-rob-m-and-ivan-sivak).

Answer (score 2):

The issue happens when you init twice.

Remove this

```
$("#days, #years").slider({
     tooltip: 'always',
}); 

$("#days").slider({
  formatter: function(value) {
    return 'Days: ' + value;
  }
});

$("#years").slider({
  formatter: function(value) {
    return 'Years: ' + value;
  }
});
```

Replace with this

```
$("#days").slider({
  tooltip: 'always',
  formatter: function(value) {
    return 'Days: ' + value; //return ('Days: ' + value).replace(",", ":");
  }
});

$("#years").slider({
  tooltip: 'always',
  formatter: function(value) {
    return 'Years: ' + value; //return ('Years: ' + value).replace(",", ":");
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uo821Lzw/

Updated: Replace comma with colon https://jsfiddle.net/5w3zms3h/

Comment: thank you but as per the answer below, check your fiddle, now the numbers are separated with a comma, while they should be `1920:1980`

Comment: you're right tho, I will match both of yours answers now, thank you

Comment: I've just updated my script with a simple string replace. You're welcome.